# Function from a sphere to the real line.

Tags: general-topology

I want to know the way to construct, and to prove that there exists a function $f: S^1\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = f(-x)$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about the zero function?

Comment: Take any function defined on a half-open semicircular arc of 180 degrees, and define the function on the rest of the circle by reflection.